# Detect if audio or video casting is active

Tags: java, android

I have recently added a system volume controller to my app & i have overlooked Casting.

The app detects a volume button click using an accessibility service, intercepts the system volume panel by broadcasting the close system dialogues intent and pops my overlay panel, allowing the user to control audio directly from the panel (alarm, music & ring).

I have already added stop checks if the user is in call or the screen is off.

Is there a way to determine if the android device is currently casting video or audio?

I have dug through several API's and they all seem to point to methods within the context of the app, nothing system wide.

Comment: You need to share code so you can get help.

Comment: There is no code relevant to the question though, I don't have a method to detect casting

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to create a MediaSessionManager instance and check for active controllers, then get the PlaybackType.

```
MediaController = null;
boolean isCasting = false;
MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager = (MediaSessionManager)  getSystemService(MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
assert mediaSessionManager != null;
List<MediaController> sessions = mediaSessionManager.getActiveSessions(new ComponentName(this, NotificationListener.class));
     for(MediaController controller : sessions) {
                try {
                    isCasting = Objects.requireNonNull(controller.getPlaybackInfo()).getPlaybackType() == MediaController.PlaybackInfo.PLAYBACK_TYPE_REMOTE;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(isCasting){
                    mediaController = controller;
                    break;
                }
            }
```